# Is there a validation listener in Vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I don't want to create a validator, rather I want to listen for any validation errors so that I can do something special.

So for example let's say I have a `DateField` and the user enters invalid date, I want to have a `listener` that will be notified at the same time as the field is highlighted in red by Vaadin. I looked everywhere I could and could not find any kind of Validation `Listener` or error notification mechanism. I can create my own custom validators, but that's not what I want to do. I want to be notified of validation errors from fields like `DateField` which already have their own built-in validators. There must be some way because some kind of listener has to be notified to change the css values for the field as well as add the question mark in the caption...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've noticed Vaadin validators don't have "listening" capabilities. I assume you want to check the date format on the fly. What I noticed is Vaadin validators don't listen but they can validate the input on submit. Since I couldn't accomplish on-the-fly input checking, I used `componentError`.

Here's an example:

```
TextField number = new TextField();

number.addTextChangeListener((FieldEvents.TextChangeEvent event)->{ // Java 8 for lambda
    if(!event.getText().matches("[0-9]+")){ // matches function for regexp
        number.setComponentError(new UserError("Must be a valid number"));
    }
    else{
        number.setComponentError(null);
    }
});
```

This will listen to changes and display an error if the user keeps entering invalid values. However, there's one more thing to do. By default, `textChangeListener` is configured in lazy mode. Lazy mode requires the user to pause typing to listen to changes. What you might want to do is to set the listening mode to eager:

```
number.setTextChangeEventMode(AbstractTextField.TextChangeEventMode.EAGER);
```

After that, you can use `getComponentError` in a button listener to forbid submitting if there's an error, where having an error means `componentError` is not null.

I know this looks like a dirty workaround but that's what was working for me. There is an [add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/viritin) which enables the support for eager validation but I couldn't get it to work properly. You might wanna look at that as well.

As far as highlighting the invalid input goes, `componentError` renders a small red exclamation mark (depends on your theme also, you should be able to configure this) over the input field which displays `UserError` when you hover on it.

Comment: I'm actually trying to avoid all this, that and I don't want to create an additional validator. Basically I just want to be notified when there is a validation error (from the built-in validators) so that I can do something. I know there is a small red exclamation point but this only works if you use the FormLayout, if I want the caption on the left and have more than one column I can't use the FormLayout any more, which means that the caption is no longer an option, which then means I need to be able to change the color of my label or something along those lines...

Comment: @StephaneGrenier I think you'll probably need some CSS configuration in your theme to display custom errors like label coloring. As for Validator listening goes, take a look at [this link](https://dev.vaadin.com/svn/doc/book-examples/branches/vaadin-7/src/com/vaadin/book/examples/component/properties/ValidationExample.java), it covers a rather basic example of validation usage.

Comment: I'm not necessarily looking for a custom error, but rather just a way to have a listener so that I can decide what I want to do when one occurs.